# Using custom material theme with linear gradient CSS in angular

Tags: css, angular, themes

I try to use a custom theme in a CSS linear gradient property in an angular web app.
My styles.css looks like this :

```
@include mat.core();

@mixin component-theme($theme) {

    $my-theme-primary: map-get($theme, primary);
    $my-theme-accent: map-get($theme, accent);
    $my-theme-warn: map-get($theme, warn);

    $color-fond-titre: mat.get-color-from-palette($my-theme-primary, 100);
    $color-titre : mat.get-color-from-palette($my-theme-primary, darker);
    $color-panel: mat.get-color-from-palette($my-theme-primary, darker-contrast);


    $color-fond-titre-accent: mat.get-color-from-palette($my-theme-accent, 100);
    $color-titre-accent: mat.get-color-from-palette($my-theme-accent, darker);
    $color-panel-accent: mat.get-color-from-palette($my-theme-accent, darker-contrast);

    .active-selection
    {
        background-color: mat.get-color-from-palette($my-theme-primary, 500) !important;
        color: mat.get-color-from-palette($my-theme-primary, darker-contrast) !important;
    }

    .card-container-background
    {
        background-image: linear-gradient(70deg, mat.get-color-from-palette($my-theme-primary, darker-contrast) , mat.get-color-from-palette($my-theme-primary, 100))
                  url('assets/icons/store-cloth.png');
    }
```

I want to use the class "card-container-background" in a template like this :

```
<div id="zone-utility-container">
    <mat-card class="card-container-background">
---------------------------------------------------
    </mat-card>    
</div>
```

What’s wrong with this code ? Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your background-image definition is not a valid CSS value, each option has to be seperated by a comma, so in your case you would have to add a comma after linear-gradient(...) like this:

```
.card-container-background
{
    background-image: linear-gradient(70deg, mat.get-color-from-palette($my-theme-primary, darker-contrast) , mat.get-color-from-palette($my-theme-primary, 100)),
              url('assets/icons/store-cloth.png');
}
```